# MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017 closed (whitelisting IP and opening the port didn't work)

Tags: database, mongodb, connection, database-connection

i'm learning MongoDB and i'm sorry to bother you but i'm getting this error:

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017 closed
at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:305:38)
at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7) {
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
servers: Map(3) {
  'ac-c9obg9r-shard-00-00.onq7cwz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
  'ac-c9obg9r-shard-00-02.onq7cwz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription],
  'ac-c9obg9r-shard-00-01.onq7cwz.mongodb.net:27017' => [ServerDescription]
},


stale: false,
compatible: true,
heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
localThresholdMS: 15,
setName: 'atlas-up12ch-shard-0',
logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: undefined
},

  code: undefined,
  [Symbol(errorLabels)]: Set(0) {}
}
```

I have tried to enable the port 27017 and resetting the ip in the network access tab (was white listed already), but no luck, error persists. Reinstalled the modules I used, and nothing.
My code was working yesterday, but after a Windows update i can't connect (that's why i thought it was the port).
The digits I replaced xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017 are not my ip number, i don't know if that helps.

If u have any ideas, I apreciate your input.

Answer (score 1):

```
MongoServerSelectionError: connection <monitor> to xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:27017 closed 
    at Timeout._onTimeout (C:\...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\sdam\topology.js:305:38)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

I had this same error while trying to connect to MongoDB with a new Node server.

See if you have changed your network connection to a diferent network than the one you have whitelisted in MongoDB.
If so, **whitelist** the **current IP adress** in mongoDB.
(PS: I see you have already tried resetting the IP address in the Network Access tab, but check again. This was how i fixed it.)

Also, check and see if the **.env** file **variables** are correctly declared with MongoDB link and also change the password and database name.

Still if the issue is not solved, I would suggest you to delete the old cluster and create a new one in MongoDB. Also re-initialise node and the packages.

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: Thanks Ramesan for your input. I found the answer to a similar problem on google and finally worked: 

Changed { useUnifiedTopology: true }) to { useUnifiedTopology: false })

If anyone is having the same issue, i recommend you do that, save and restart the server.

Answer (score 1):

For me this error was occurring because my connection string was wrong.To be very specific - I copied the sample connection string from a course I was learning and just replaced the username and password with my credentials. So, the credentials were right but not the rest of the connection string.

Just for the sake of understanding. Please see below :

`mongodb+srv://myusername:mypassword@courseproject.h1mpg.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority`"

**myusername** and **mypassword** are correct i.e belong to the cluster in my atlas account but the rest of the string is wrong as I copied it from somewhere instead of copying it from my own MongoDB atlas account.

So please make sure to double check if your entire connection string is correct.

Answer (score 1):

```js
import { MongoClient } from 'mongodb'
const uri = process.env.MONGODB_URI
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true, 
  useUnifiedTopology: true, 
}

client = new MongoClient(uri, options)
clientPromise = client.connect();

export default clientPromise
```

Inside your .env you could insert something like this:

```
MONGODB_URI=mongodb+srv://username:password@name-of-cluster.i43pl8d.mongodb.net/DatabaseName?retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

Code snippet for connnecting mongodb will be available at https://cloud.mongodb.com/, navigate to your cluster and click `connect` then click `Connect your application`. [image]

Finally copy code snippet whatever you get at your time of mongodb version after choosing `include full driver code example` and implement it into your application:
[image]

Comment: This wans't my issue, but thanks for adding another solution. Maybe it will be helpful for someone else.

Comment: @MavS 
{
reason: TopologyDescription {
type: 'ReplicaSetNoPrimary',
}
Your error speaks of the reason, so I have reproduced the same error without including 
const options = {
  useNewUrlParser: true, 
  useUnifiedTopology: true, 
}
Kindly try this

Comment: Again, thanks. But i already solved it months ago. Hope someone else finds it useful.